# Concatenating String and Saving to Text File using PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

What is the problem in my PB script below, the text file returns an output of "H NAME" - opening and closing quote was included inside the text file upon saving and it should have been H NAME only. I've already run in debug mode and the value of ls_Message is H    NAME which is correct but when saving into the text file it became "H    NAME". What happened? Below is the script.

```
ls_Message = "H" 
ls_Message += "~t"
ls_Message += ls_ITSUPPORTNAME

ll_hdr_insert = dw_Outbound.InsertRow(0)
dw_Outbound.SetItem(ll_hdr_insert,'message',ls_Message)         
IF Trim(ls_Message) <> "" OR Len(Trim(ls_Message)) > 0 THEN ls_Message = ""

FilePath = String(dw_path.Object.outboundfilepath[1])
FileName = ls_FilePrefix + String(ldt_TranDate,'YYYYMMDDHHMM') +'_'+ ls_RefereceNum + '.txt'
FileDir = FilePath + '/' + FileName
dw_Outbound.SaveAs(FileDir, TEXT!, FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you post the code in which you save this to file?

Comment: @DARKinVADER, i have posted the script of saving the file.

Comment: can you try removing the ~t concat in your ls_message and see if it will still have -> " "

Comment: @Sid You hit the nail on the head. When a tab is present in the data, the data is quoted to distinguish the data tab from the delimiter tab. This is the way a tab-delimited file should (and needs to) work. If the data was unquoted, the process receiving the file would identify the data tab as a column delimiter, and the import process would either import the data incorrectly, or choke & die. If this file is intended for import as a tab-delimited file somewhere else, I'd leave things along and appreciate that PB caught this for you; if it's not for import, I'd go with the File*() functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DataWindow.SaveAs() (I'm guessing, since it isn't explicit in your question at this point), you're relinquishing some control of the format to the generic functionality (which wasn't really designed for *just* creating a text file; it's more for staging data of mixed types for some other use).

It sounds like what you really want is the PowerScript functions FileOpen(), FileWrite() and FileClose(). With those, you control the format.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Hi Terry, Yes I'm using the DataWindow.SaveAs( ). I used to export customized formats using Datawindow.SaveAs( ) even before in the applications that I've created but anyway i will explore with FileOpen(), FileWrite() and FileClose(). Thanks.

Comment: I think he is creating a file that outputs lots of rows and PowerScript functions will do help but what using datawindow would be better than FileOpen -> FileWrite -> FileClose. jmtc